# Export to Excel from React & Electron - "Excel Style Definition Example"

Tags: ios, excel, reactjs, electron, ag-grid

I have copied the sample called "Excel Style Definition Example" into a .js file in my React application.  I have the enterprise version of ag-grid.

The first line of the sample code calls function: getBooleanValue() as follows:

```
  var columnWidth = getBooleanValue("#columnWidth") ? getTextValue("#columnWidthValue") : undefined;
```

This is failing with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
getBooleanValue
src/containers/ManagerBoard/ManagerBoard.js:198
  195 | }
  196 |  
  197 | function getBooleanValue(cssSelector) {
> 198 |     return document.querySelector(cssSelector).checked === true;
  199 |   }
  200 |   function getTextValue(cssSelector) {
  201 |     return document.querySelector(cssSelector).value;
```

Please advise.  Thank you.
Victor Reinhart

Comment: Does `#columnWidth` exist on your page?

Comment: No it does not.  But in the sample code, #columnWidth does exist in the index.jsx file.  I will look into that some more, thank you!